# Сравнение дат с применение Moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Есть две переменные:

```
var last_state_tim_strt = moment(last_state['TimStrt'], 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').valueOf();
var current_state_tim_strt = moment(state['TimStrt'], 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').valueOf();
```

Как сравнить по дате?

```
 if (moment(last_state_tim_strt, 'YYYYMMDD', true).format() == moment(current_state_tim_strt, 'YYYYMMDD', true).format()){
 /* ... */
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moment.js предоставляет методы для сравнения дат - isBefore(), isAfter() и isSame(). Соответственно своим названиям, они возвращают булево значение, если одна из дат была до, после, или же они равны. Пример использования isAfter() показан [здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=2043)

Comment: Cделал так  if (moment(last_state_tim_strt).isSame(current_state_tim_strt, 'day'))