# Неправильное сравнение дат в jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetime, momentjs

Есть два инпута (datetime-local) - from и to, в который пользователь вводит временной промежуток, например: от (from) 20.06.2018 09:00 до (to) 29.06.2018 17:00. Если текущая дата и время меньше from, в select ставим "не проводился", если между from и to - "идет сейчас", если больше to - "завершен". Но почему то мой код очень странно отрабатывает, ввожу 20.06.2018 09:00 до 02.07.2018 17:00 мне выводит "завершен", хотя должен "идет сейчас". Может быть вы подскажите почему так? Вот ссылка на Codepen **codepen.io/EYur/pen/dKjRQO**
Заранее всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы пытаетесь строку сравнить со строкой.
Чисто для эксперимента, что будет если выполнить подобное условие?

```
if ('25.06.2018 20:00' > '01.07.2018 10:00') { 
    console.log('true!')
} else {
    console.log('false!')
}
```

Переведите дату в секунды и сравнивайте их. У момента есть свое сравнение дат, можете его попробовать, описано тут - [Сравнение дат с применение Moment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587895/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-moment?rq=1)